# Does using abusive and bad words for the companions of Muhammad take one out of the fold of Islam?

Tags: sahaba, kufr

Do abusive and bad words used for companions of Muhammad SAW take one out of Islam?

Please give me feedback with authentic hadith and also Quran verses.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, it makes them a hypocrite

---

First of all, no one should have any reason to disrespect the [Sahaba](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sahabah)(Companions of the Prophet). They are the ones who supported Islam, fought the Mushrikeen, sacrificed their wealth and theirselves for Allah. Allah chose them to be the Companions of the Prophet.

Allah said:

> "Muhammad is the Messenger of Allah, and those who are with him are hard against the unbelievers, merciful to the believers..." ([48:29](https://quran.com/48/29))

and

> "The outstrippers, the first of the Muhajirun and the Ansars," ([9:100](https://quran.com/9/100))

and

> "Allah was pleased with the believers when they gave allegiance to you under the tree," ([48:18](https://quran.com/48/18))

and

> "Men who were true to their contract with Allah." ([33:23](https://quran.com/33/23))

---

It was narrated that al-Bara’ (may Allaah be pleased with him) said:

> I heard the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) say:
>
> “The Ansaar: no one loves them but a believer and no one hates them but a hypocrite. Whoever loves them, Allaah will love him, and whoever hates them, Allaah will hate him.”
>
> Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 3672; Muslim, 75.

If a man who hates the [Ansaar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansar_(Islam)) cannot be a believer, they are hypocrites. Those who slander, curse and denounce the [Ansaar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansar_(Islam)) and [Muhajireen](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhajirun) after what they done for Islam makes them a kaafir and hypocrite.

Al-Tahhaawi said, discussing the beliefs of Ahl al-Sunnah wa’l-Jamaa’ah:

> We love the companions of the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) and we do not neglect to love any one of them, nor do we disavow any one of them. We hate those who hate them and who criticize them, and we only mention them in good terms. Loving them is part of religious commitment, faith and ihsaan, and hating them is kufr, hypocrisy and wrongdoing.

In Sharh al-‘Aqeedah al-Waasitiyyah, it says:

> This is an important basic principle which the Muslims should understand, namely loving and respecting the Sahaabah, because that is part of faith. Hating them or hating one of them is kufr and hypocrisy, because loving them is part of loving the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) and hating them is part of hating the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him).

Abu Zar’ah al-Raazi said:

> If you see a man criticizing one of the companions of the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him), then know that he is a heretic.

Imam Ahmad said:

> If you see a man mentioning one of the companions of the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) in a bad way, then call his Islam into question.

---

To summarise, disrespecting the Companions of the Prophet is a major sin that will make them a hypocrite. Hypocrisy is **more dangerous than kufr.**

Allah says in the Qu'ran:

> “Verily, the hypocrites will be in the lowest depth (grade) of the Fire; no helper will you find for them
>
> [[al-Nisaa’ 4:145](https://quran.com/4/145)]

There are many other verses in the Qu'ran which talks about the hypocrites.

And Allah knows best.

---

Source: [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/45563) and [Sunnah.org](http://www.sunnah.org/msaec/articles/attack.htm)